# Get the two most recent git tags (and the log between them)

Tags: git, tags, git-log, git-tag

I am looking for a git command that would show me the `git log` between the **two most recent tags** in the current branch.

I.e. if the two most recent tags are `build_341` and `build_342`, then I would want to end up with the output of `git log build_341..build_342`

I know that I can get the most recent tag using `git describe --abbrev=0`, but I don't know how to show the second most recent tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's possible to get the second most recent tag using:

```
git describe --abbrev=0 $(git describe --abbrev=0)^
```

So I can get a log between the two most recent tags using:

```
git log $(git describe --abbrev=0 $(git describe --abbrev=0)^)..$(git describe --abbrev=0)
```

Not pretty, but it seems to work (as long as your shell supports `$()` command substiution). Other answers are welcome.

Comment: I was playing with this, and it looked promising, but watch out for the "^" syntax -- if the prior commit is a merge, it's possible that you could get a different tag from the one you expected.  (I haven't found an alternative, though.)

Answer (score 0):

If you have the situation where the HEAD is a merge commit, I found this solution to return the most recent tag among the parent commits, using PowerShell.

```
# Find the latest tag for each of the current commit's parents.
$parentsTags = git rev-parse HEAD^@ | ForEach-Object { 
    git describe --tags --abbrev=0 $_
}

# Out of all the tags, sorted oldest-to-newest, find the last one that's also one of the parents' tags.
$nextLatestTag = git for-each-ref --sort=creatordate --format '%(refname)' refs/tags `
    | Split-Path -Leaf `
    | Where-Object { $parentsTags.Contains($_) } `
    | Select-Object -Last 1
```